# changing colors in ls?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, ls

Is there a way to change the colors for directories etc for `ls` while using gnu `screen`? I have tried using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console) but it doesn't work.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6325/nested-ssh-session-inside-screen-has-no-color/6349#6349 for some troubleshooting steps and possible solution, which is to try this: `dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors; echo "TERM $TERM" >> ~/.dircolors`

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to mention that this is on OSX.

Turns out that [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91937/mac-os-x-dircolors-not-found) solved the problem.